# Return Values for Single Row when when multiple rows are returned (LookupRows)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I'm currently trying to figure out how to return values from a specified row when multiple results are returned:

For this case I'm going to show an example from [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) since my code is very similar:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @region, @rank, @i

set @region = AttributeValue("Region") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @region = "North" /* or a literal value */

set @rank = AttributeValue("Rank") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @rank = "1" /* or a literal value */

set @rows = LookupRows("LoyaltyMembers","region", @region, "rank", @rank)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

output(concat("region: ", @region))
output(concat("<br>rank ", @rank))

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @emailAddress, @firstName, @rank
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @firstName = field(@row,"firstName")
    set @emailAddress = field(@row,"emailAddress")

    ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, firstName: %%=v(@firstName)=%%, emailAddress: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Output:

```
region: North
rank: 1
Row 1, firstName: Doug, emailAddress: doug@limedash.com
Row 2, firstName: Barb, emailAddress: barb@limedash.com
```

As you can see, multiple arguments are used in the `LookupRows` function and the proper result is displayed. - This roughly mimics my scenario.

However, in my case, when multiple rows are returned I want to only display values from one of the rows that I specify.

For instance, let's say that there is another column named `size` Doug's size is `Large` and Barb has no value for `size`.

How can I further specify the desired output? I've assumed adding the additional condition in the loop like so:

```
if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @emailAddress, @firstName, @rank
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @firstName = field(@row,"firstName")
    set @emailAddress = field(@row,"emailAddress")
    set @size = field(@row,"size")
    ]%%

        <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, firstName: %%=v(@firstName)=%%, emailAddress: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%
    
        %%[
    
      next @i ]%%
    
    %%[ elseif empty(@size) then /*Something here to just pull values from one row?*/]%%
    
    No rows found
    
    %%[ endif ]%%
```

But I am having trouble getting the syntax right and second-guessing the possibility of this being valid.

How can I do this when multiple rows are returned?

Answer (score 1):

It is not 100% clear want you want to achieve and I see there are 2 different approaches:

1. If you would want to always display only one row then it is better to check [Lookup](https://ampscript.guide/lookup/) function with several field conditions and maybe even mix it with some `IF-ELSE-ENDIF` conditions as well.
2. If you would want to conditionally reduce the number of displayed rows from the [LookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) function - it implies that the returned number of rows could be still more than 2 (where `@size` is not empty in your example). The code would be something like -

```
%%[
if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        var @emailAddress, @firstName, @rank
        set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
        set @firstName = field(@row,"firstName")
        set @emailAddress = field(@row,"emailAddress")
        set @size = field(@row,"size")
        ]%%

        %%[ IF NOT EMPTY(@size) THEN ]%%
        <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, firstName: %%=v(@firstName)=%%, emailAddress: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%, size: %%=v(@size)=%%
        %%[ ENDIF ]%%
    
    %%[next @i ]%%
    
%%[ else ]%%
    
No rows found
    
%%[ endif ]%%
```

In your code, you could not do it because `@size` is not set up in the `ELSEIF` path. So you gotta limit the number of rows within the loop just before outputting them.

Comment: This is close to what I'm trying to explain. I opted for the lookuprows function because I need to use multiple arguments in my lookup to display the desired output

Comment: so has my answer helped you or what is the problem if not?

Comment: Additionally, your second point is also valid. - The issue is that multiple rows are returned and I only need values from one of those rows. I'm trying to figure out how to return a single row conditionally (if that makes sense).

Comment: I see your edit and will try this approach later at the office. If it works I'll mark correct.

Comment: Can you be more specific, @Dr.Tenma on which row exactly you need to display? First, last or a random one?

Comment: Hi @Lukas Lunow, when multiple rows are returned then I would like to only use values from one of the rows. For instance, with the example I provided I want to say in the for loop    `set @firstName = field(@row,"firstName")
    set @size = field(@row,"size") if @size == "large" then set @firstName = "Ted"` and then only return the row where that is true.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma why not use multiple criteria in LookupRows function in first place? It supports adding more than one field to the filter.